# SQL table not obeying its unique constraint

Tags: sql, sqlite

I set up an SQL table in sqlite3 with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE "userstrings" (
    'user_id' INTEGER NOT NULL,
    'cat_id' INTEGER NOT NULL,
    'name_id' INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT unq UNIQUE(user_id, cat_id, name_id)
)
```

I'm still wiring up the user interface but I noticed in the table there were four rows all with user_id = 10, cat_id = 8, and name_id = NULL.

Does NULL somehow circumvent unique constraints? Ultimately, the goal is to only allow unique rows, and to allow name_id to be null.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite does not consider multiple `NULL` values are counting towards a violation of a unique constraint (nor do several other major database).  [See here](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q26) for the SQLite documentation on this.

So using `NULL` as a placeholder may not behave as intended in the context of a unique constraint.  One possible workaround would be to use a different placeholder value, e.g. `-1` instead.  The following `INSERT` statement would fail:

```
INSERT INTO userstrings (user_id, cat_id, name_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1);
```

Whereas had the `name_id` values both been `NULL`, the insert would have succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ANSI standards, a UNIQUE constraint should not allow duplicate non-NULL values but does in fact allow multiple NULL values.

The SQL standard requires that a UNIQUE constraint be enforced even if one or more of the columns in the constraint are NULL however SQLite does not enforce this rule.